# Scroll Bar keeps jumping down

Tags: excel, vba, scrollbar, userform

I am making a userform on excel using vba and every time i enter a row into the listbox the scroll bar jumps down one row making it invisible and inaccessible. Any idea what I can do?

I want the scroll bar to remain at the bottom of the listbox but stay there and not disappear. Any idea what i can do?